# How can I compare more than 2 condition in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
angle1 = int(input('Please enter the 1st angle:'))
angle2 = int(input('please enter the 2nd angle:'))
angle3 = int(input('please enter the 3rd angle:'))
Angle = angle1 + angle2 + angle3
while Angle == 180:
    if angle1 and angle2 and angle3 < 90:
        print ('this an actue triangle')

    elif angle1 or angle2 or angle3 == 90:
        print ('this is a right triangle')

    elif angle1 or angle2 or angle3 > 90: 
        print ('this is an obtuse triangle')

    Angle = angle1 + angle2 + angle3    
    angle1 = int(input('Please enter the 1st angle:'))
    angle2 = int(input('please enter the 2nd angle:'))
    angle3 = int(input('please enter the 3rd angle:'))
```

I tried to compare each angle with a condition but it seem whenever I enter number in angle3, it will just compare to the condition and ignore the other two angle. Please help me with this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `any` and `all` functions.

```
ask = lambda: [int(input('Please enter the {0}st angle:'.format(i))) for i in range(1,4)]
angles = ask()
while sum(angles) == 180:
    if all(a < 90 for a in angles):
        print ('this an actue triangle')

    elif any(a == 90 for a in angles):
        print ('this is a right triangle')

    elif any(a > 90 for a in angles):
        print ('this is an obtuse triangle')

    angles = ask()
```

**EDIT:** Some comments for Python beginners:

First line, I used a lambda expression which is a one-line function. In the lambda expression, I used a list comprehension (a compact way to build a list).

So `ask()` returns a list containing the 3 angles e.g. `[90, 45, 45]`.

You can find information about `sum()`, `any()` and `all()` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

Comment: Some of your function is new to me which I can't use because I haven't study it yet, but thanks for helping me anyway.

Comment: @Isaac Ok I understand. There are useful built-in functions. It is the occasion to learn!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to compare each single angle like this

```
if (angle1 < 90) and (angle2 < 90) and (angle3 < 90)
```

Same for the other conditions. But i think you have to use or instead of and in the if statements. Because when Angle is 180 all three angles cant be smaller than 90 and you just want to test if one of three angles is smaller than 90. with and all conditions has to be true.